# SPFX Extension ListView - nothing happens after "loading debug scripts"

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

I've build the demo listview extension through yo @microsoft/sharepoint... after trusting the dev-cert and gulp serve I received

> Do you want allow debug scripts

after confirming with yes... nothing happens :(

```
...
 @override
  public onRefreshCommand(event: IListViewCommandSetRefreshEventParameters): void {
    event.visible = true; // assume true by default

    if (this.properties.disabledCommandIds) {
      if (this.properties.disabledCommandIds.indexOf(event.commandId) >= 0) {
        Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, 'Hiding command ' + event.commandId);
        event.visible = false;
      }
    }
  }
...
```

my url parameters looks like that:

```
?loadSPFX=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js&customActions=%7B"a5b8e4c8-9a51-4d02-b605-fd7af9af90bb":%7B"location":"ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar"%7D%7D
```

the guid is already replaced with the right one in `HelloWorldCommandSet.manifest.json`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently, SPFx extensions have moved from preview to RC. So, this has introduced some breaking changes for extensions. MS has deprecated `onRefreshCommand` method and suggested that you use the `onListViewUpdated` method.

Reference - [List view command set changes](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/extensions/changes-between-dev-preview-and-rc)

Since, it looks like you are just beginning to start working on SPFx extensions, I would suggest that you upgrade the `Microsoft/sharepoint` yeoman generator to the latest one.

To, upgrade the generator, simply run the below command in the command line:

```
npm update -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@latest
```

After, that, run the generator again(`yo@microsoft/sharepoint`) and follow the steps that you currently implemented.

After you create a new extension, the method will be as below:

```
@override
  public onListViewUpdated(event: IListViewCommandSetListViewUpdatedParameters): void {
    if (this.properties.disabledCommandIds) {
      for (const commandId of this.properties.disabledCommandIds) {
        const command: Command | undefined = this.tryGetCommand(commandId);
        if (command && command.visible) {
          Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Hiding command ${commandId}`);
          command.visible = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Works for me :)

Comment: @Gautam Sheth even with the latest updates am having the same issue